# JAVA Robot mouse event not working on login screen of oSX mavericks but works on lower version

Tags: java, macos, awt, awtrobot, mousepress

I run a java application in login window using LaunchAgents ,which captures mouse and keyboard events remotely and executes it. The keyboard events work properly but not the mouse events.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ash.login</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <string>LoginWindow</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
        <string>-jar</string>
        <string>-Dapple.awt.uielement=true</string> (Works sometimes without this option)
        <string>/Library/Ash_Agent/data/remote.jar</string>
    </array>    
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

captureImage.robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); (Used inside the code)

I'm not able to gain control of the mouse at loginwindow. Works fine in aqua or when logged in.
****Console errors :****

```
Untrusted apps are not allowed to connect to or launch Window Server before login.
Window Server is not available
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because Robot internally uses CGEventPost rather than the deprecated CGPostMouseEvent, but CGEventPost doesn't work prelogin.

Comment: Chromium remoting seems to do CGEventPost for keyboard events in pre login, and it works, can you check and tell?

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/remoting/host/input_injector_mac.cc?rcl=0&l=50